# Публикация веб админки на flask с ботом на aiogram

Tags: python, ubuntu, aiogram, flask, интерфейс

Есть созданная админка на flask для бота на aiogram, как можно опубликовать flask приложение что бы можно было получать доступ к нему из интернета и запустить бота на aiogram, на ubunty(Не нашел понятных гайдов как можно было бы это сделать)

Или лучше сделать админку с помощью другого фреймворка?

Answer (score 0):

Для более надежного функционирования бота рекомендуется арендовать VDS-сервер. Это позволит разместить код на удаленном сервере и обеспечить возможность управления ботом через интернет. Кроме того, вы можете запустить бота на своем собственном сервере с Ubuntu для тестирования и разработки